# Python Stack Out of Bounds Error

Tags: python, list, stack, indexoutofboundsexception

I get an index out of bounds error on my `push` method for a stack.

I'm trying to implement a postfix style logical calculator in python. Where for instance `0!1&1!0=!1/|` will evaluate out to 1 or true.

I implement this using a stack and the common methods associated with such a list "push" and "pop" But I'm not allowed to use the typical append or remove methods that one might fine in this sort of implementation. Instead I have to initiate the list to a standard size equal to the length of the expression that I will be performing my evaluation on.

I do this with my method called `evaluate` by referencing a global integer called `top` that points to the the top of the stack and is incremented or decremented within depending on whether I call `push` or `pop`.

My `push` method is as follows

```
def push(stack, element):
    global tos
    tos += 1
    stack[tos] = element
```

My `pop` method is as follows

```
def pop(stack):
    #stack = None
    global tos
    tos -= 1
```

Essentially, I read through each individual element of the string using

```
for i in expression
```

Then I say, `if i ==` (some expression): perform a premade method.

Here's are a couple examples from my code found within this loop that iterates through the expression

```
if op == "1":
    push(theStack, True)
elif op == "0":
    push(theStack, False)
elif op == "!":
    pop(None)
    push(theStack, Not(theStack[tos]))
elif op == "&":
    pop(None)
    pop(None)
    push(theStack, And(theStack[tos], theStack[tos + 1]))
```

I tested the `pop`, it seems do what is should. I think the error is with my `push`.

I initiate `tos` to -1, also this is a quick peak at the top of my method that the loop is found in

```
def LogicalEval (expression):
    global tos
    theStack = [len(expression)]

    def Not(expr):
        if expr == True:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def And (expr1, expr2):
        if expr1 == True and expr2 == True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I do not initiate the stack at any point outside of `LogicalEval`, in fact I'm limited to just three main methods (`push`, `pop`, `LogicalEval`) outside of my helper methods such as `And` and `Not` that are found in `LogicalEval`

Comment: Please fix the formatting. If you leave 4 spaces before each line, it will highlight it as code.

Comment: So how did you define the stack here?

Comment: Also, what is the *initial* value of `tos`?

Comment: Also I forgot to mention that I initate tos to -1

Comment: @user3106485: you can add that to your question, just [edit] it.

Comment: I do not initate the stack at any point outside of LogicalEval, in fact im limited to just three main methods (push, pop, LogicalEval) outside of my helper methods such as "And" and "Not" that are found in LogicalEval

Comment: sorry about that, and thanks martijin

Answer (score 3):

You created a stack with **one** element:

```
theStack = [len(expression)]
```

`len()` returns an integer, so you created, given an expression of 5 charcaters, the following list:

```
theStack = [5]
```

so you'll *rapidly* run out of space.

Create the list like this:

```
theStack = [None] * len(expression)
```

Multiplication on a sequence repeats that sequence. `[None]` is a list with one element (the `None` sentinel value) and multiplying that by the length of the expression creates a list with that many elements.

Next, your handling of the operands on the stack is incorrect for `!` and `&`:

```
elif op == "!":
    pop(None)
    push(theStack, Not(theStack[tos]))
elif op == "&":
    pop(None)
    pop(None)
    push(theStack, And(theStack[tos], theStack[tos + 1]))
```

You want to either retrieve the stack values *first*, then `pop()`; or adjust your `tos` offsets to take into account they are already decremented, or otherwise alter your `pop()` function to *return* the popped value.

Currently, when you run `!` (boolean *NOT*), you move from `tos == 0` to `tos == -1`, then push `Not(theStack[-1])` back onto the stack. That's not what you want to do here, as `theStack[-1]` is the *very last element in your stack*, and not part of the active stack right now.

Then you execute `&` (boolean *AND*) on a stack with `tos == 2` and pop **twice**. Now you are at `0` again and try to address `theStack[0]` and `theStack[1]`. Here the offsets from the stack are entirely incorrect; you just removed two from the `tos` then add 0 and 1, addressing the two values *below the old top of the stack*.

I'd personally go for a `pop()` function that returns the top of the stack as well as adjust the `tos` pointer:

```
def pop(stack):
    global tos
    tos -= 1
    return stack[tos + 1]  # value at old position
```

then use that to take your operands from the stack:

```
elif op == "!":
    push(theStack, Not(pop(theStack)))
elif op == "&":
    push(theStack, And(pop(theStack), pop(theStack)))
```

Comment: When would I call push on a binary operation such as "&" when the top of the stack "tos" is at the 0 position though? There has to be at least 2 elements in the stack which means that the lowest index for the top of the stack/tos would be 1. If that were to occur then there would be an error in the expression provided.. rather than an error in my code. I do however, feel as though my offsets still might be a bit off even with this in mind

Comment: @user3106485 right, that is an error on my part; travelling now so correction has to wait a minute or so. Sorry!

Comment: Hey I got everything working perfectly, thanks so much for your help Martijn Pieters!!

Answer (score 0):

`theStack = [len(expression)]` *doesn't* create a list of length `len(expression)` - it creates a list of length 1, containing the value  `len(expression)` in `theStack[0]`.

To create a list of given length, you can do

`theStack = [0] * len(expression)]`

Which will initialise the `len(expression)` elements of `theStack` to zeroes.

Comment: Oh well, you were beaten with nunchakus :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I should've known better than to try and ninja _the Ninja_ :)